# What is the fastest way to swim in the sea?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

This has been bugging me ever since the wetsuit update for ACNH came out. I've always thought the fastest way to swim was by mashing the A button repeatedly so that your character does that arm movement thing over and over, but I also found out that by holding the A button, your character can just calmly kick their legs and swim faster that way too.

I tested this out, and I'm pretty positive that mashing the A button makes you go faster, but my mind could just be playing tricks on me. So with that being said, do I go faster by repeatedly pressing the A button? Or am I better off just holding A?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Mashing** the A button does make you go faster. However, certain sea creatures are disturbed by this movement, and will swim away from you.

Conversely, **holding** the A button will propel you slower, but less alarmingly, allowing you to approach skittish shadows with ease.